# I am trying to draw a clustering Euclidean diagram

Tags: pgfplots, graphics

I am a biochemistry graduate student, and I have classified breast tumours using a Euclidean centroid-based approach with 437 up-regulated and 370 down-regulated genes (dimension = 807). I would like to draw a simple 2D diagram (`x = 0-10`, `y = 0-10`) with two centroids, and colour-coded points to demonstrate the principle in two dimensions. Something similar to this:

[image]

But with the X in green and blue as well. The axes don't need to be labelled. I would greatly appreciate to be redirected to a similar post/answer. Thank you very much for your time!

EDIT:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        width=\linewidth,
        title={K-means Predictions ($k=2$)},
        xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=10,
        xlabel={Gene 1},
        ylabel={Gene 2}
        ]
       \node[text=blue,font=\sffamily\bfseries,scale=2] at (3,3) {X};
       \addplot+[y filter/.expression={y+10},only marks,mark=*,samples=50,domain=1:5] {40*rnd};
       \node[text=red,font=\sffamily\bfseries,scale=2] at (7,7){X};
       \addplot+[y filter/.expression={y+50},only marks,mark=*,mark options={fill=red},samples=50,domain=5:9] {40*rnd};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First check out the "Reated" links to the right.  Basically you want a scatter plot (see pgfplots) and possibly import the data from another file (see pgfplotstable).  The easiest way to place the symbols is to add another scatter plot with two entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how those dots are distributed, hence in this they are random. The method is quite manual in the sense that one has to adjust the domain, the position of `X` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        width=\linewidth,
        title={KMeans Predictions ($k=2$)},
        xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=100,
        xlabel={Eruption time (minutes)},
        ylabel={Time between eruptions (minutes)}
        ]
       \node[text=blue,font=\sffamily\bfseries,scale=2] at (3,30) {X};
       \addplot+[y filter/.expression={y+10},only marks,mark=*,samples=50,domain=1:5] {40*rnd};
       \node[text=red,font=\sffamily\bfseries,scale=2] at (7,70){X};
       \addplot+[y filter/.expression={y+50},only marks,mark=*,mark options={fill=red},samples=50,domain=5:9] {40*rnd};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can put the `X` any where by adjusting the coordinates say `(3,30)` in

```
\node[text=blue,font=\sffamily\bfseries,scale=2] at (3,30) {X};
```

Change blue here to whatever you want. Similarly the mark (dots) position can be changed by adjusting

```
\addplot+[y filter/.expression={y+10},only marks,mark=*,samples=50,domain=1:5] 
{40*rnd};
```

In this adjust the `domain`, `fill` in `mark options` and the number (10) in `y filter/.expression={y+10}` suitably.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        width=\linewidth,
        title={KMeans Predictions ($k=2$)},
        xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=100,
        xlabel={Eruption time (minutes)},
        ylabel={Time between eruptions (minutes)}
        ]
       \node[text=blue,font=\sffamily\bfseries,scale=2] at (3,70) {X};
       \addplot+[y filter/.expression={y+50},only marks,mark=*, samples=50,mark
            options={fill=olive},domain=1:5] {40*rnd};
       \node[text=red,font=\sffamily\bfseries,scale=2] at (7,50){X};
       \addplot+[y filter/.expression={y+30},only marks,mark=*,mark options={fill=green},samples=50,domain=5:9] {40*rnd};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! I truly appreciate it! I hope that it's not too much to ask but how could I modify your code so that I keep the same points, but put the X's somewhere else and re-colour the points accordingly? I want to make two pictures showing how re-computing centroids works... Thank you! I'll award the bounty when stackexchange allows me!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have been learning latex to write my thesis for 4 months now. I made progress. With your example, I can study how you did it. I find it much more efficient and faster to learn this way than reading disconnected tutorials. :)

Comment: Hi Harish, how are you? I'd like to have the exact same graph but with y-scale max of 10. I changed the y-axis and centroids coordinates. The later appear, but not the dots. I am sure that it is something silly. I have edited my original post to show my code. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Johnathan Use `y+1` and `y+5` respectively and `{4*rnd}` for both

Comment: @Thank you! What does the "y" and {4*mean}. I understand the other commands , except y filter/ .expression={y+1}.